# Dynamic Variable in KornShell Script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, ksh

**This KornShell Script (ksh):**

```
envir=Dev
eval "${envir}foo=bar"
echo "$Devfoo"
```

**Output:**

```
bar
```

But I will not know what value is assigned to `envir` variable. So I want to do something like this where the output is the same as above:

```
envir=Dev
eval "${envir}foo=bar"
echo "${${envir}foo}"
```

**Output:**

```
${${envir}foo}: bad substitution
```

Comment: is this ksh88 or ksh93?

Comment: Not sure, but I assume ksh88.

Comment: Try `ksh --version` or `what $(which ksh)`

Comment: `--version: 0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command.` 

The `what $(which ksh)` command has a lot of output. Not sure what to look for.

Comment: What would be a better title for this question?

Answer (score 2):

For ksh93, you have (at least) a couple of choices

1. associative arrays

   ```
   envir=Dev
   foo["$envir"]=bar
   echo "${foo["$envir"]}"
   ```
2. namerefs

   ```
   nameref var=${envir}foo
   var=bar
   echo "$var"
   ```

For ksh88, you may be stuck with eval:

```
envir=Dev
name="${envir}foo"
eval "$name=bar"
eval "echo \$$name"
```

Comment: I must have ksh88 because only the `eval` solution worked.Thank You!

`ksh: Dev: 0403-009 The specified number is not valid for this command.`


`ksh: nameref:  not found.`